# Swift: Have no idea how to call my delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I am newbie in Swift. And I completely cannot understand delegates. I have two view controllers and I need to set var for another controller I want use delegate for it. I googled a lot of topic here but nothing helps. My view controller B has a var myFlag which I want to set from view controller A. Here the view controller B code

```
protocol flagDelegate {       
    func anyFlag(flag: Bool!)
}

class myBViewController: UIViewController {    
    var myFlag: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println("myFlag: \(self.myFlag)")   
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        println("myFlag: \(self.myFlag)")   
    }

    func anyFlag(flag: Bool!) {
        self.myFlag = flag
    }
}
```

View controller A has a button which load view controller B with code:

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myNC") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

myNC is a Navigation Controller which holds View Controller B. I have no idea how to set delegate and call it. Could you help me, please! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the view controller A is setting a property on a view controller it's about to show (view controller B), you don't need to use the delegate pattern. The delegate pattern is for communicating backwards (from B to A).

So you can set a property before presenting the view controller like this:

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myNC") as! UINavigationController

    // get a reference to your VC
    let rootViewController = navigationVC.viewControllers[0] as MyBViewController

    // set the property
    rootViewController.myFlag = true // or false

    // or you could call the method you wrote
    rootViewController.anyFlag(true)

    // present the view controller
    self.presentViewController(navigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I've tried it but I get "'Application tried to present modally an active controller" error.

Comment: Well then your VC is already visible. But that's a different question.